# Telerik RadComboBox Items not getting checked

Tags: c#-4.0, telerik, telerik-grid, radcombobox

I have a search page where i select some parameters and hit submit I store sessions  and get results in radgrid.And on the double click of the row i go to the edit page..
I am capturing radcombobox.text into a session..example Session["Status]=active,inactive,old
I am retrieving the session on !postback to keep the values back from edit page..

Sample code...

I tried the below code to get the items in combobox get chked when they return from edit page...

Not sure why its not checking the items in RadCombobox.Please advise

```
                     if (Session["Status"] != null)
                    {
                        ddlStatus.Text = Session["Status"].ToString();

                        string status = Session["Status"].ToString();

                        string[] words = status.Split(',');


                            foreach (RadComboBoxItem item in ddlStatus.Items)
                            {

                                string strtext = item.Text.ToString();
                                if (strtext.Length > 0)
                                {

                                   if(ddlStatus.Items.Any(x => words.Equals(x)))
                                   {
                                       item.Checked = true;
                                   }

                                    else
                                    {
                                        item.Checked = false;
                                    }

                            }
                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tried your code all you have to do just modify the foreach to be :

```
foreach (RadComboBoxItem item in ddlStatus.Items.ToList())
{
                                //   if(ddlStatus.Items.Any(x => words.Equals(x)))


                                     if(words.Contains(item.Text))
                                   {
                                       item.Checked = true;
                                   }

                                    else
                                    {
                                        item.Checked = false;
                                    }

}
```

and it would work.